# How to wait for initial data loading in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```dart
// main.dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<LoginProvider>(create: (_) => LoginProvider()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        routes: {
          '/' : (context) => LoginPage(),
          MainPage.routeName : (context) => MainPage(),
          RecipePage.routeName : (context) => RecipePage(),
          FoodPage.routeName : (context) => FoodPage(),
          LoginPage.routeName : (context) => LoginPage()
        },
      )
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
// login_provider.dart
class LoginProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  static const String KEY_IS_LOGIN = "IS_LOGIN";
  static const String KEY_USER_ID = "USER_ID";

  User _me;
  bool _isLogin;

  LoginProvider() {
    setup();
  }

  void setup() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _isLogin = prefs.getBool(KEY_IS_LOGIN) ?? false;

    if(_isLogin) {
      String uid = prefs.getString(KEY_USER_ID);
      if(uid == null) {
        prefs.setBool(KEY_IS_LOGIN, false);
      } else {
        User user = await DBHelper.getUser(uid);
        
        if(user == null) {
          prefs.setBool(KEY_IS_LOGIN, false);
        } else {
          _me = user;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  bool get isLogin => _isLogin;

  void setLogin(String id) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool(KEY_IS_LOGIN, true);
    prefs.setString(KEY_USER_ID, id);
  }

  User get me => _me;

  set me(User value) {
    _me = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

```dart
// parts of DBHelper(db_helper.dart)
static Future<User> getUser(String uid) async {
  http.Response response = await http.get('http://$IP:3000/user/$uid');
  if(response.body == '{}') return null;
  return User.fromJsonString(response.body);
}
```

I have to get data from server when the app is start.

In `MultiProvider`, I called `LoginProvider`'s constructor.

And In `LoginProvider`'s constructor, I called `setup` function that load user data from server if user id which is in `SharedPreferences` is valid. (if user id is invalid, set `isLogin` false.)

So, My app has to wait until user data is completely load.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1 - Create splash page and call, await `setup` from there and navigate to login page afterwards.

2 - Call and await `setup` from login page. Until the method is finished you need to show some loading widget.

You need to change `setup` to `Future<void>` so we can await for the method, and call it from login page / splash page and not from the constructor.

```
  Future<void> setup() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _isLogin = prefs.getBool(KEY_IS_LOGIN) ?? false;

    if(_isLogin) {
      String uid = prefs.getString(KEY_USER_ID);
      if(uid == null) {
        prefs.setBool(KEY_IS_LOGIN, false);
      } else {
        User user = await DBHelper.getUser(uid);
        
        if(user == null) {
          prefs.setBool(KEY_IS_LOGIN, false);
        } else {
          _me = user;
        }
      }
    }

  }
```

Either login/splash page options you need a method that looks like this:

```
initState() {
super.initState();
// set initial loading widgets
loadDataFromModel();
}

void loadDataFromModel() async {
await Provider.of<LoginProvider>.setup();
setState(() {
// set your login widgets after the model fetched data
}) 
}
```

Or you can use alternative `FutureBuilder` (attached `setup` future to the builder and handle connection state)

Comment: Thanks! I solved it: `await Provider.of<LoginProvider>(context, listen: false).setup();`

Comment: Thank you guys, you saved me hours of troubleshooting